# Arrows Arrowhead

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw(0,0) 
 node [scale=6,thick]{$\circlearrowright$}
(0,0) node{$I_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Yields:
[image]

I would like the arrowhead to be filled in like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's already something about this here. [Certainly several examples on using arrows with TikZ can be found...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tikz%20arrows) But arrows are specified as an option to the `\draw` command. If you say `\draw[->]` whatever you tell LaTeX to draw there's going to be an arrow head at the end.

Furthermore there are *a lot* of arrow tips available to be used, the Default one from tikz is something like the one you have shown so you have to specify one that suits your Needs. Check [the manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) under **Part III**, **Arrows**. There's also the `arrows.meta` library that lets you customize arrow tips.

Here's an example that Shows how to draw what you want and three kinds of arrows, from left to right: tikz default arrow, LaTeX arrow and Stealth arrow.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw[->] (0,0) node{$I_1$} ++(80:0.5) arc[start angle=80, delta angle=-350, radius=0.5];
\draw[-latex] (1.1,0) node{$I_1$} ++(80:0.5) arc[start angle=80, delta angle=-350, radius=0.5];
\draw[-stealth] (2.2,0) node{$I_1$} ++(80:0.5) arc[start angle=80, delta angle=-350, radius=0.5];
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]